# ASP.net Invalid URL redirect (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, web

I am using custom Errors tags to redirect to a page when ever an url is not found.

```
  <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

But the case is this [image]

This is my page and the url is correct and it loads and works correctly. But whenever i type clients.aspx/Something it dosent redirect to the error page neither it loads properly.
[image]

So i want it to redirect to the error page or remove that unwanted string from url and load the page correctly.

Can someone help me to get an idea how to do that ?  thank you.

Comment: Please Explain your question with some code

Comment: Use URL Rewriting.

Comment: I don't know the how-to's in WebForms, but in MVC I catch all the errors and throw them to their own handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this for default redirect:

```
  <configuration>
         <system.web>
                <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/error.aspx" mode="On" />
         </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Also try this on different errors as per http error codes:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/error.aspx">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
          <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPages/403.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use if you want to avoid extra character from the url:

[Server.Transfer()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800(v=vs.90).aspx)

It transfer to another page but in the same/Current url..